# Access files from different projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, file-upload, file-access

I have 2 projects , one is web application and another is WPF. In my web application I have a upload page to allow users to upload their files. I used `Server.MapPath(@"~/something/")` for the directory, but how do I retrieve that file in my WPF application ?

I can retrieve by typing the full path ***C:/programfiles/projects*** ... etc , but I am retrieving the directory from the database and in the database it reads like that ***~/something/filename.jpg*** .

How to  access the file with only ***~/something/filename.jpg*** ? There is an error saying path does not exists unless I type the full path in but i don't want that .

Comment: `Server.Mappath` looks for the file in the specified directory from the root directory of the web application. I am not aware of any such extension in WPF. The best thing you can do it is try to append the `Application.Path` to the value retrieved from the database, provided the file is present in a sub directory of the current app. May be this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) helps.

Comment: Yes but the directory only exists in the web aplication , not in my WPF

Comment: In that case you need to store the absolute path of the directory(EX: C:\YourWebApp\) in your app config and then append the value from the database (remove ~).

Comment: Can u show me an example ? thanks